# How to specify rmarkdown render_site encoding?

Tags: html, r, character-encoding, knitr, r-markdown

When generating the html file with knit html from a rmarkdown file, I had no encoding issue.

However when I did with this function `rmarkdown::render_site()`, I had this problem. Even when I specify the encoding option this way:

```
rmarkdown::render_site(encoding="utf-8")
```

For example, this special character "è" become this "Ã¨"

Comment: Related: https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown/issues/712

Comment: Thank you for your comment @Yihui, however, this didn't work. In the html generated, I can read in the header : 
<head>

<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta name="generator" content="pandoc" />

Comment: I reinstalled rmarkdown, and now I have this error : Error: pandoc version 1.12.3 or higher is required and was not found (see the help page ?rmarkdown::pandoc_available). Then I found this downloading link : http://pandoc.org/installing.html